# Anonymous class as member of class

Tags: android, parcelable, anonymous-class

I have found this in an article. It implements Parcelable for passing data between activities in Android

```
public class Student implements Parcelable {

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public Student createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Student(in);
    }

    public Student[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Student[size];
    }
};

private long id;
private String name;
private String grade;

// Constructor
public Student(long id, String name, String grade){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setGrade(String grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}

// Parcelling part
   public Student(Parcel in){
       this.id = in.readLong();
       this.name = in.readString();
       this.grade =  in.readString();
   }

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeLong(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.grade);
   }

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", grade='" + grade + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

In this example, a field CREATOR is declared and implements Parcelable.Creator Interface.This is an anonymous class.Does this mean anonymous classes can also be created as members of a class? and I have learnt from other sources that Anonymous classes cannot be static, but here it is declared as static. I don't understand the context of anonymous class in this example.Can someone explain this?

Comment: you can use this lib https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean anonymous classes can also be created as members of a class?

You can store the anonymous class instance reference to a field, yes.

> and I have learnt from other sources that Anonymous classes cannot be static, but here it is declared as static

It's true that anonymous classes cannot be explicitly `static`. But they can be used in a static context (as in the example you posted - initialising a static field) which makes them implicitly static. Java language spec covers this in [15.9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.2):

> Let C be the class being instantiated, and let `i` be the instance being created. If C is an inner class, then `i` may have an *immediately enclosing instance* ([§8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)), determined as follows:
>
> If C is an anonymous class, then:
>
> - If the class instance creation expression occurs in a static context, then `i` has no immediately enclosing instance.
> - Otherwise, the immediately enclosing instance of `i` is `this`.